# Как скопировать файл через Python без импорта модулей?

Tags: python, файлы, функции

Нашел такую задачу:

1. Попросите пользователя ввести команду «read» или «copy».
2. Попросите у пользователь ввести путь к файлу, содержимое которого он хочет посмотреть, либо скопировать. Причём, если пользователь ввёл до этого «read», то надо написать: «Напишите путь к файлу, содержимое которого Вы хотите посмотреть:». А если была команда «write», то: «Напишите путь к файлу, который Вы хотите скопировать:»
3. Если была команда «read», то вывести пользователю содержимое файла.
4. Если была команда «write», то сделайте копию файла. Копия файла должна называться так же, как и исходный файл, и находиться она должна в директории files, находящейся в той же директории, что и файл скрипта.

P.S. По-моему в задаче ошибка и вместо write должно быть указано copy.

У меня возникла проблема па решению 4-ой части. Единственные варианты - это решение через модуль shutil. Прошу помочь написать его без этого модуля (если это возможно)

Вот остальная часть кода:

```
while True:
    a = input("Введите read или copy: ")
    if a == "read":
        b = input("Напишите путь к файлу, содержимое которого Вы хотите посмотреть: ")
        d = "r"
        try:
            c = open(b, d)
            print(c.read())
            c.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Путь указан неправильно, попробуйте ещё раз")
            continue
        break
        #дальше надо написать через elif a == "copy": .......
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ, но я уже придумал ещё один работающий вариант

```
    elif a == "copy":
    b = input("Напишите путь к файлу, который Вы хотите скопировать: ")
    d = "r"
    try:
        c = open(b, d)
        m = c.read()
        c.close()
        t = input("Напишите путь файла, в который Вы хотите скопировать содержимое: ")
        d = "a"
        c = open(t, d)
        c.write(m)
        c.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Путь указан неправильно, попробуйте ещё раз")
        continue
    break
```

Comment: Это неполный кусок кода, который не может быть рабочим.

Comment: более того, он не выполняет п.4 условий задачи

Answer (score 1):

Задача хочет от вас что-то такое:

```
    newfile = b.split('/')[-1]
    with open(b, 'r') as c:
        with open('files/' + newfile , 'w') as w:
            w.write(c.read())
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import shutil
while True:
    print()
    print("1.Посмотреть файл - R\n2.Скопировать файл - C\n3.Записать скопированное содержимое в другой файл - W\n4.Выход - E")
    command = input('Введите команду текстом - ').lower()
    match command:
        case "e":
             print('Выход из программы')
             exit()
        case "r":#1
            path = input('Напишите путь к файлу, содержимое которого Вы хотите посмотреть: ')
            try:
                h = open(path,'r')
                print(h.read())
                h.close()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print('Файл с указанным именем не существует')
        case "c":#1
            path = input('Напишите путь к файлу, который Вы хотите скопировать: ')
            path2 = input('Напишите путь к файлу, куда Вы хотите скопировать: ')
            try:
                shutil.copy(path,path2)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print('Файл с указанным именем не существует или некорректно указана дирректория')
        case "w":
            path = input('Напишите путь к файлу, содержимое которого Вы хотите скопировать: ')
            try:
                h=open(path,'r')
                text = h.read()
                print('Информация скопирована')
                h.close()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print('Файл с указанным именем не существует или некорректно указана дирректория')
            
            path2 = input ('Укажите путь куда вы хотите сопировать файл и название файла с атрибутами -')
            try:
                h=open(path2,'w')
                h.write(text)
                print('Файл создан, текст скопирован')
                h.close()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print('Файл с указанным именем не существует или некорректно указана дирректория')
        case _: print('Неизвестная операция')
```

Comment: В вопросе: "без импорта модулей", смотрим ответ: сразу в первой строке кода `import shutil`